# Using a function before defining it in PHP

Tags: php

in C++, all functions must be defined before using them. In PHP, can I use a function before defining it? Will it be slower?

Comment: What are you talking about? The only "using" I know is in C#.

Comment: @taspeotis: Not everybody bothers to backtick their keywords. But good call.

Comment: @taspeotis i don't know what you mean.

Comment: @lovespring: `using` is a keyword in C#. What taspeotis means is that the word "using" in the English language does not always refer to `using` in C#.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since PHP is an interpreted language—not a compiled one—the order does not usually matter, since the contents of the script are parsed prior to the code being executed. There are a few exceptions, particularly when the existence of a function is conditional on some other code being executed.

You can read about this topic in the PHP manual here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 3):

In C++, we need to declare a function before using it. Not so in PHP: functions need not be defined before they are referenced.